# Lightning component : call apex function after window.location

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning, attachment, pdf

In lightning, is it possible to call an Apex function just after a `window.location.href` ?

For example I have a function that save a pdf from a visualforce page into attachment, and in the lightning component, when I click a button, I want that the pdf (visualforce page with `renderAs="pdf"`) is displayed and just after I want that the function saving the pdf to be called

```
window.location.href = "my location";
var action = component.get("c.attachPdf");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A browser, once instructed to go to a different page, automatically closes all of its open connections to the server and begins the process of removing all elements from memory. In other words, once you "leave" a page, there's absolutely nothing more that you can do script-wise, including calling to a server, saving page state into local storage, or anything else. Instead, call the Apex function first, and in the callback, perform your redirect.

Answer (score 3):

Window.location.href completely gets you in a new context and window and hence you cannot do this .

When you move away from the component to a new browser window everything is destroyed .

All you can do at that point is to pass some URL parameters and take some actions based on that